# Calculate $\sum\limits_{i=2}^\infty\sum\limits_{j=2}^\infty \frac{1}{j^i}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series

Calculate $\sum\limits_{i=2}^\infty\sum\limits_{j=2}^\infty \frac{1}{j^i}$. I am trying to figure out how to calculate this. I know it must be $\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}\sum\limits_{i=2}^k\sum\limits_{j=2}^k\frac{1}{j^i}$ but I am not sure how to do this?

Comment: Hint: sum over $i$ first.

Comment: So $\frac{1}{j^2}+\frac{1}{j^3}+\frac{1}{j^4}+\frac{1}{j^5}$...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint** (as first proposed by achille hui in the comments above): $$\sum_{i=2}^\infty j^{-i}=\frac{1}{j(j-1)} \; , \;\;j>1$$

**EDIT:**

The above is a geometric series $\sum_{i=0}^\infty r^i=\frac{1}{1-r}$ with $r=\frac{1}{j}$ where you have to subtract the first two terms (since $i$ runs from $2$ and not $0$).

Comment: You should also argue that exchanging the order of summation doesn't change the limit - this is not generally true for doubly infinite sequences, but is true when the series is absolutely convergent (as it is here), by Fubini's theorem.

Comment: @Mark For this case, it is easier to use Tonelli (as all terms involved are obviously non-negative).

Comment: @Mark Since the summands are nonnegative, its allowed even if the sums are infinite.

Comment: Thank you for all the input! Why is it that $\sum\limits_{i=2}^\infty j^{-1}=\frac{1}{j(j-1)}$?

Comment: @user320195 it is a geometric series.

Comment: @user320195 See my edit.

Comment: @user320195 Note: I just corrected a mistake in the edit, sorry for the potential confusion. You can read more about geometric series here: http://www.purplemath.com/modules/series5.htm

Comment: (+1) My answer is simply an expansion on each of the steps involved in applying your hint. I hope you don't mind.

Comment: @robjohn Not at all!

Answer (score 3):

$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{i=2}^\infty\sum_{j=2}^\infty\frac1{j^i}
&=\sum_{j=2}^\infty\sum_{i=2}^\infty\frac1{j^i}\tag{1}\\
&=\sum_{j=2}^\infty\frac{\frac1{j^2}}{1-\frac1j}\tag{2}\\
&=\sum_{j=2}^\infty\frac1{j(j-1)}\tag{3}\\
&=\sum_{j=2}^\infty\left(\frac1{j-1}-\frac1j\right)\tag{4}\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{j=2}^n\left(\frac1{j-1}-\frac1j\right)\tag{5}\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1-\frac1n\right)\tag{6}\\[12pt]
&=1\tag{7}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$(1)$: since all terms are positive, apply [Tonelli's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini's_theorem#Tonelli.27s_theorem_for_non-negative_functions)
$(2)$: use the [Formula for the Sum of a Geometric Series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Formula)
$(3)$: simplify the summand
$(4)$: apply [Partial Fractions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_fraction_decomposition)
$(5)$: apply the definition of an [Infinite Series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Series_%28mathematics%29#Definition)
$(6)$: compute the [Telescoping Sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series)
$(7)$: evaluate the limit

Answer (score 0):

Notice:

- $$\sum_{n=a}^{\infty}\frac{b}{n^c}=b\zeta(c,a)\space\text{ when }b=0\vee\Re(c)>1$$
- $$\sum_{n=a}^{\infty}\frac{b}{c^n}=\frac{bc^{1-a}}{c-1}\space\text{ when }|c|>1$$

So, to solve your question:

$$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\sum_{m=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{m^n}=\left[\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\left[\sum_{m=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{m^n}\right]\right]=\left[\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\left[\zeta(n)-1\right]\right]=1$$